# Finite index subgroups of the mapping class group with geometric meaning

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory

I have got a question that is perhaps not precise in a mathematical sense. 
Is there a classification of all coverings of the moduli space of Riemann surfaces which are moduli spaces themselves, that is, they parametrize some geometric structure on a surface.

Comment: You may be referring to the congruence subgroup problem: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0901.4663

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is a "classification", but there are some interesting examples. Two which come to mind: Harer's description of the moduli space of a Riemann surface with spin structure; and Torelli space.

EDIT: Oops, I forgot to read your title, I just read the text. Torelli space is an infinite rank covering of moduli space.